# For-loop not returning all values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a piece of code that's meant to be implemented in Google Charts, however, not all values I'm looking for are being returned.

I need a couple of dates selected from my database, and I select them as follows:

```
$dates = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM participants WHERE subdomein='testdomain'")) or die(mysql_error());
```

Then I use a for-loop to echo them:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($dates); $i++)
    {
        echo $dates[0].' ';
    }
```

In my database there are 3 (distinct) dates: `24-03-2013`, `25-03-2013` and `26-03-2013`, however the piece of code returns `2x 24-03-2013`. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I also tried a while-loop but that loops infinitely or crashes my page. Besides that, I tested the query by running it in the database itself and it returns the right results, so the query works fine.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: there might not be any row to loop through

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row()` only fetches one row.  You need to call it repetitively from within your loop.

Comment: is your query correct? Does your query return the 3 values you're expecting?\

Comment: the `mysql_` functions are deprecated (and will be removed), you should use PDO or mysqli instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_row()` inside a loop in itself:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM participants WHERE subdomein='testdomain'");
while($date = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo $date[0];
}
```

You should also note that the `mysql_*` family of functions are not deprecated. You should avoid using them if possible, and look into alternatives such as MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `mysql_fetch_row()` fetches only one row, If you need all the rows use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM participants WHERE subdomein='testdomain'");

while($dates = mysql_fetch_assoc() ($sql)){
   print_r($dates);
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row` only returns one record from the actual result of your query. You have to call it several times, ontil it returns `null` :

```
$res = mysql_query(...);

while (($record = mysql_fecth_row($res)) !== null) {
    print_r($record[0]);
}
```

Please note `mysql_*` function are deprecated and should not be used anymore, too.